# Migrating onlyoffice community server in Windows

Tags: onlyoffice

We have installed a Onlyoffice Community Server in our company on a Windows system.

We need to migrate all these data to another Windows server (version 2012). If I go to settings I don't see the option of Data Management to do the backup and restore.

I am getting the results for migrating community server between Windows and Linux servers, but nothing for Windows and Windows.

Please help us with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the first part of the [instruction](http://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/windows/community/migrating-to-linux.aspx) for migration community server between Windows and Linux servers. You need to copy folders and create your database dump file. Then restore dump file and folders on the new server.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)